# Dot Trace show waiting for CPU while excuting multiple ASP.NET MVC actions

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, dottrace

I am currently trying to improve the performance of my Asp.Net Application. During this I have found out that when I call the same action multiple time or different action within the same controller through ajax call, it takes the unequal amount of time. Please refer below image.

[Timeline of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhxQz.png)
On digging using Dot trace tool, I found that this difference is being traced as "Waiting for CPU" i.e. task is waiting for thread assignment. How can we optimize this so that all the same actions get equal amount of time to execute their functionality.

Comment: Possibly post the code?

Comment: Hi @GrantGarrison, in the action, I am just returning a hard coded interger. Sometimes it takes equal time, sometimes difference is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU is at his max capacity. Close unused program to freed some CPU activity